# Определить один ли остров

Tags: алгоритм, поиск

Дана матрица M[r][c] заполненная нулями и единицами. Нуль - море, 1 - суша.
Островом считается суша окруженная морем по столбцам или по строке. Остров не может быть внутри острова.
Задача найти количество островов.
Пример:
**In**

[[0, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 1],
[0, 1, 0]]
**Out**

3
**In**

[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
**Out**

1
**In**

[[1, 0, 1],
[0, 1, 1]]
**Out**

2
**In**

[[1, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 1]]
**Out**

1
Вопрос: какие алгоритмы решают похожую задачу, или идеи решение данной задачи.

Comment: https://www.careercup.com/question?id=5708658983829504

Comment: Вам нужен поиск связных компонент графа. Для этого можно просто найти все соседние вершины поиском в ширину/глубину.